# Custom WebApi routing not working

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a custom route for a web api controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
public class AdminApiController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("~/echo")]
    public string Echo()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I expect to go to `http://example.com/api/admin/echo` and receive 'Hello world' but in stead I get an error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://example.com/api/admin/echo'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'admin'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the tilde (**~**)

A tilde (~) on the method attribute overrides the
[route prefix](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes) of the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
public class AdminApiController : BaseApiController {
    // GET /api/admin/echo
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("echo")] 
    public string Echo() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    // GET /echo
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/echo")]
    public string Echo2() {
        return "Hello World 2";
    }
}
```

Just to be safe you also need to make sure that you [Enable Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable)

To enable attribute routing, call **MapHttpAttributeRoutes** during configuration. This extension method is defined in the **System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions** class.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion, I get `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'` when going to `sample.com/api/admin/echo`

Comment: @Andrey I updated the answer to include `HttpGetAttribute`.

Comment: Actually, the route prefix is still not working. It worked when the controller was named AdminController. When it's named Admin`Api`Controller I'm forced to use `/api/adminAPI/echo` url and not `api/admin/echo` - any ideas why?

Comment: Did you configure the mapping? I provided that in the answer as well.

Comment: You mean do I run config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() - yes I do. I didn't add any custom mappings explicitly, as I assumed that RoutePrefix will override controller name - otherwise why would we need RoutePrefix at all?

Comment: Did you check the links to the articles provided

Comment: You also need to make sure that you configure the mvc and webapi in the correct order or else you will get conflicts. Show your config code.